# How to store textfile data as variables and then calculate values using those variables?

Tags: python

I am new to python and I have a textfile that looks like this:

```
0       10
0.01    10.0000001
0.02    10.00000113
0.03    10.00000468
0.04    10.0000128
```

which are the first few values for time and velocity respectively.

I want to read that textfile into Python and use those values to create variables for time and velocity in order to find the acceleration.

So far I have:

```
t = []
v = []

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        first, second = line.split()
        t.append(first)
        v.append(second)


print(t)
print(v)
```

And now I am unsure where to go next.

Ideally I want to calculate the acceleration at the corresponding times and then write that into a new textfile that has [time, acceleration], looking something like:

```
0       acceleration_value1
0.01    acceleration_value2
0.02    acceleration_value3
0.03    acceleration_value4
0.04    acceleration_value5
```

Comment: Think about how you would do it by hand. You should note that your acceleration list should not have an acceleration for the first time. When moving from position-->velocity and then velocity-->acceleration, you lose the first point because there's nothing before it to compare it to. Anyways, start working on how you would do it by hand and then try to implement it. Remember `a = change_in_velocity / change_in_time`.

Comment: Yeah I do get the jist of what I have to do on paper but since I'm pretty new to python I don't know where to start with the coding part. How do I even implement a function where it takes in the previous 2 values of velocity and time in order to give acceleration, whilst making sure it takes in those values in the data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, or tutorial resource.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your code is already there, however it is lacking the conversion to `float` from the string read from file. Besides that, a simple loop should do the job.

```
t = []
v = []

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        first, second = line.split()
        t.append(float(first))    # note the 'float' conversion here
        v.append(float(second))

# Now, we will use an array to store the acceleration values
# The first element in this array will be zero, so:
a = [0]

# To calculate the acceleration, we will do delta(v)/delta(t),
# To calculate any delta, we will iterate each array, and pick
# the "current" and "previous" element. For this reason, our index
# will start at 1 skipping the first (otherwise we'll go to -1)

# these steps could be combined, but I feel it helps beginners to see
# the process

for i in range(1, len(v)):    # since v,t have same length, just pick either
    delta_v = v[i] - v[i-1]
    delta_t = t[i] - t[i-1]
    acc = delta_v / delta_t
    a.append(acc)

# Now we can print
# 'zip' combines the two arrays as columns of a matrix,
# so now "x" picks a value from "t", and "y" from "a" 
# as we iterate
for x, y in zip(t, a):
    print("%s  %s" % (x,y))

# or save to file:
with open("acceleration.txt", 'w') as f:
    for x, y in zip(t, a):
        f.write("%s  %s\n" % (x,y))
```

Comment: @no clue Glad it helps: keep coding!

Answer (score 0):

This should give a list of the acceleration for each timestamp

```
t = []
v = []

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        first, second = line.split()
        t.append(first)
        v.append(second)

acc = []
for i in range(len(t)):
  if i == 0:
    acc.append(0)
  else:
    acc.append((float(v[i]) - float(v[i-1])) / (float(t[i]) - float(t[i-1])))

print(acc)
```